# Refurbishing mountain bike - left standing for couple of years

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, restoration

I've a Marin Rocky Ridge (2007) that I'd like to give a bit of an overhaul/refurbish as it's been left standing for two years or so. I'm just looking to know where would be common areas that would have degraded over time? Would brake fluid etc. need replacing, as well as bearings needing cleaned/ regreased?

This is a link to the bike spec (may need to select "Show detailed spec") [2007 Marin Rocky Ridge Spec](http://www.thebikelist.co.uk/marin/rocky-ridge-2007)

Comment: Standing where?  Inside in a dry, heated area, in poorly sealed a shed or lean-to, or outside in the weather?

Comment: Inside a garage, would have been dry enough but not heated. (I'm in the UK so cold enough winters)

Comment: The chain should be cleaned and lubed, of course, and possibly the hydraulic brake fluid should be changed/flushed.  And you need to carefully inspect the tires for signs of rot.  The bearings should be fine unless it got excessively hot in the garage for long periods.

Comment: At most it would have been in the mid 20C (77F) for a few weeks.

Comment: That should be fine.  Check the bearings (as you should do occasionally with any bike) for play and for any sign of sticking/"indexing", but no need to repack them unless the check shows a problem.  As to the brake fluid, it depends a lot on whether there may have been high humidity and condensation which somehow got into the fluid (and it depends on the type of fluid).  (And there's also a chance the brake calipers may be sticky to start with, so give them time to "break in" before going hot-dogging.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now then, seeing as it's been in a garage, it's obviously collected dust. Not too far off being collecting enough to seize some bearings. First, wash the bike clean. I mean, make it very clean. You don't want to work on a dirty bike that'd make any new parts dirty, as well. warm water, washing up liquid and a sponge is great. Clean from top to bottom, not the opposite way round, as it makes two job for yourself. Once you've done that, rinse it. A pressure washer is fine in this case because we will be servicing the bearings anyway, so it doesn't matter. If you weren't going to service the bearings, don't use a pressure washer, or avoid bearings and other sensitive parts, as you could blast out all the grease.

Nip down to a local bike shop (LBS) and buy some good quality degreaser, Teflon grease, chain lubricants that vary in styles (wet environments, dry environments, etc) and try to get hold of some good cleaning equipment in your house or, again, shop. Tear up some small or old clothes, too, as these are something you would not be able to live without.

I do this every two weeks, but this is something to do every year or so. It also is suitable for much older bikes:

Take apart all your bearing-containing components. Yup, that's right. Headset, Bottom Bracket, Wheel Hubs, Pedal Axles, you name it. Strip it all down, degrease it, re-grease and reassemble. Tighten and adjust so there is no play, and no binding. That's the harder part done...

Replace all the cable inner and outers and make sure they are adjusted; PROPERLY!

Check ALL OF YOUR BOLTS. If you're feeling extra-kind, take them off and re-grease them, then reassemble it all again.

Take out your seat post and re-grease it. You would be surprised how much this can help you out in the long run... Do the same for the "steering wheel" (handle bars, was just wondering if anyone gets the reference). Take them out the stem and re-grease where it would contact the stem. Again, this WILL help.

Please, for the love of GOD, please check the wear on your brakes and tyres. I have lost a few friends due to them having literally no brake pad left and running metal on metal, and I mean, they died during crash incidents.

Other than the super-basic lubing chain, bleeding hydraulic brakes, pumping up tyres and realigning your handlebars and saddles, that's really it.

If you're lazy, just get the bike shop to service the bike.

*
*
*
*
*
*

DO:

-Check that the wheels are aligned

-Wipe off excessive grease/lubricants. This will collect dirt, turn into a grinding paste and literally sand your components down.

-Use good/great quality components. These may not last any longer than cheaper parts, but they reduce wear and tear on other parts, and they feel much nicer for slightly longer.

-Dry the bike after washing it. A dry towel, a microfibre cloth, even an air compressor. Dry the bike.

-Make sure the degreaser has been cleaned off and dried. What's the point of putting grease on de-greaser? *IRONY OVERDOSE!!! IRONY OVERDOSE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*

*
*
*
*
*
*

DON'T:

-Leave your tools out after you've finished. If you do, you should not be owning them. Treat them like you care about them, otherwise they won't last long. And, you'd probably lose them when you really need them.

-Use a pressure washer on freshly-serviced bikes. Not unless you want to have to service the thing again in a few weeks.

-Buy parts from people on eBay with low amounts of feed back. If they have thousands of positive feedback, buy from them. If they send you something faulty and refuse to allow you to send it back, you can open a case. Almost every time, you'll get to send the product back free of charge. They won't lose an account earning thousands of pounds over a twenty pound tyre set. 5/10 times, they'll let you keep the item and refund you fully!

-Don't always trust a bike mechanic at a bike shop. They told me that I had a damaged shifter which would need replacing. Took the part home, looked at the cable and saw it wasn't seated correctly. Reseated the cable and worked like new. Left negative feedback and demanded an explanation, they shut down. DON'T TRUST ALL BIKE MECHANICS UNLESS THEY CAN PROVE THE PROBLEM!!!

Have fun with the bike servicing! Hopefully it'll work like new. Don't forget, if the chain and cassette is worn, replace them. Or, just replace them for the hell of it. The bike will feel much better.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @yollooool. Err ... there's no need to SHOUT!

Comment: Hmmm, currently wondering why my answer's been down-voted? Lol, nothing said incorrectly, no lies, etc. Awww well, just proves that all forums have haters.

Comment: I suggest that you check out the [help] to learn how the site works :-)

Comment: Doesn't say much, and I've not really given any lies out, so why would I get down-voted? lol, purely haters. :3

Comment: I pointed out the PROBLEM without downvoting, but apparently someone else agreed with me and also chose to add a vote. There's nothing involving hatred. If you *really* read the [help], then you would know that labeling people in such a way could attract censure. This is actually a very friendly site, but there are rules.

Comment: So simply using CAPITAL LETTERS would cause me to become downvoted? i guess i should stop using grammar, lol. 

I am very happy with this site so far, but I don't see why everything has to have a down-vote for the slightest of things like cap-locking VITAL parts. I use capitals to outline key parts, although assuming the site has the plugin, I could use a very vague *fonting with asterisks*.

I know that it was a problem that you pointed out, but "shouting" isn't much of a problem, it is literally the same as a font change without changing font. Thanks for helping with explaining.